# Problema com um campo Booleano no asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Minha aplicação que gerencia **Cursos** tem uma área do **Administrador** onde ele aprova um **aluno** em um **curso**. Esse *campo* que **Aprova** um aluno é um campo `booleano`, só que estou com problemas com esse *campo* `booleano` ao marcar o `checkbox`, essa alteração para `true` não está sendo salva no **banco de dados**, e ao atualizar a página de **aprovação** o campo permanece vazio sem estar marcado.

**Minha Action**

```
 public ActionResult Aprovar()
    {
        return View(db.AlunoCursos.Include(ac => ac.Aluno).ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Aprovar(int id)
    {
        var alunoCursos = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.CursoId == id && ac.Aluno.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        alunoCursos.Aprovado = !alunoCursos.Aprovado;
        db.Entry(alunoCursos).State = EntityState.Modified;    


        db.SaveChanges();

        return View(db.AlunoCursos.Include(ac => ac.Aluno).ToList());
    }
```

**Minha View** `Aprovar`

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.AlunoCurso>
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Aprovar Aluno</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(ac => ac.Curso))
{

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @item.Key.Nome_Curso
                </th>
                <th>
                    Aprovado?
                </th>
            </tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var alunoCurso in item.ToList())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(_ => alunoCurso.Aluno.Nome)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => alunoCurso.Aprovado, new { @class = "Aprovado", id = item.Key })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".Aprovado").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Aprovar/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("Aprovação feita com sucesso!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

Ao **debbugar** estou tendo esse **erro**

> O dicionário parâmetros contém uma entrada nula para o parâmetro 'id'
>   do tipo não-nulo "System.Int32" para o método
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Aprovar (Int32)' em
>   'MeuProjeto.Controllers.AlunoCursosController'. Um parâmetro opcional
>   deve ser um tipo de referência, um tipo anulável, ou ser declarado
>   como um parâmetro opcional \ r \ nNome fazer parametro:. Parâmetros.

**Alguém pode me ajudar a resolver isso?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente você está passando o valor errado nessa atribuição:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => alunoCurso.Aprovado, new { @class = "Aprovado", id = item.Key })
```

O seu método `Aprovar(int id)` espera receber um ID de **AlunoCurso** para buscar esse aluno na base de dados, mas você provavelmente está passando outra variável que não é um **int**. Pelo que vi, o correto seria:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => alunoCurso.Aprovado, new { @class = "Aprovado", id = alunoCurso.CursoId })
```

Dessa forma, você estaria passando o **ID** do **AlunoCurso** atual corretamente para o método `Aprovar(int id)`.

Comment: agora ele tá salvando, mas não no Aluno que selecionei para marcar como aprovado

Comment: Pode me ajudar @Alvaro ?

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
 @model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.AlunoCurso>
 @{
     Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
     <h2>Aprovar Aluno </h2>

@foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(ac => ac.Curso))
{

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @item.Key.Nome_Curso
            </th>
            <th>
                Aprovado?
            </th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var alunoCurso in item.ToList())
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(_ => alunoCurso.Aluno.Nome)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => alunoCurso.Aprovado, new { @class = "Aprovado", value = item.Key })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Aprovado").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Aprovar/",
                type: "POST",
                data: { id: $(this).val() },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Aprovação feita com sucesso!");
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Colocar a propriedade `int?`.

Isso ocorre porque precisa ter algum valor no campo, se for obrigatório precisa passar esse valor, caso contrario colocar como aceita nulo.

Comment: Acho que para o tamanho da pergunta uma resposta um pouco mais detalhada seria necessária.